# Using Codeigniter Routing

Tags: codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I have two controllers in my CI:  `teacher` and `exams` . I have set teacher as the default controller using `$route['default_controller'] = 'teacher/index'` in the file `routes.php`. So  when i type the url `http://localhost:8080/New/` 
*(`New` is the name of my project folder)* , the default controller is loaded. but when I type `http://localhost:8080/New/exams` it says that `The requested URL /New/exams/index was not found on this server.` 
What Should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call it like this

```
http://localhost:8080/New/index.php/exams
```

If you want to remove the index.php you should edit your .htaccess in the root folder :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /New/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|javascript)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```